# how to create a HTML-Table in Email with input of Database query

Tags: html, talend

i have a query on a Database which give me Infomation like this:
[image]

i want to create a HTML Table with Information of the query above and send it to Email of Developer as Error Notification.
Can you help me with the HTML code?. 
Thankyou alot!

Comment: Thankyou very much Abhishek. i am really new with Talend. Can you please explain more detail?. Do i need to create a new tjavaRow and connect it with tjavaflex?

Comment: I would request you to post your requirement as a new question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to achieve what you have been trying for -

Job Layout -

[image]

Now, for your use case you would get the data from `database` - I had manipulated the data to be retrieved from `tFixedFlowInput`. Once you have the data retrieved you would need to perform few `html` formatting through `tJavaFlex` like below -

[image]

Once done, stored the entire content in a context variable and refer the same in your tSendMail - > "Message".

Also, make the following change to your tSendMail component to use the `HTML` formats -
[image]

Output -

[image]

**Note:** there are many formatting features which could be used through `HTML tags`, please use them as needed as per your use case - scenario.

**Edit:** Yes you would be able to check if there are any rows returned from your Db-Input. Ex: global variable `((Integer)globalMap.get("tMSSqlInput_2_NB_LINE"))` would let us know how many lines are returned by the query. Based on this result use `RunIf` trigger
`((Integer)globalMap.get("tMSSqlInput_2_NB_LINE")) > 0` and connect to your job flow so that mail would be send when there are records retrieved from `database`.